# Removing need for sudo on Vagrant box

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

When I need to install Node packages or doing something like `composer self-update` I have to prefix all commands with `sudo`.

How can I reconfigure my Vagrant instance (or the Ubuntu 14 OS) to ignore the need for `sudo` when connected via SSH?

I tried the following already:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

However, I am getting permission problems when any Node packages try to install any other packages (such as Yeoman generators).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot *remove* the need for sudo.
However, you can temporarily become root to enter a group of commands without typing sudo every time. This doesn't remove the *need* for sudo which is always there, but it lets you bypass it for a short while.
`sudo su root` will give you root permissions until you exit  the command shell or log off. To remind you to be very careful, the command prompt changes to `#`. Type `exit` to go back to a normal command shell.